# place pin on mapview by coordinates sent from appdelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

This takes me days..I could not make it work.
I write a method that places a pin on map as below:

```
- (void) SetMaps:(NSString *)Lats :(NSString *)lons;
{
    if([upLo isEqualToString:@"Y"])
    {
        NSLog(@"setting maps:%@,%@",Lats,lons);
        [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
        region.center.latitude = [Lats doubleValue] ;
        region.center.longitude = [lons doubleValue];
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
       [mapView setDelegate:self];
        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        point.coordinate = region.center;
       [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];

    }
}
```

This method runs well if I call it in secondViewController.m in a tab bar controll application.

But, I want to call it from appdelegate.m.
So in appdelegate.m, I put

```
secondViewController *Gper=[[secondViewController alloc]init];
[Gper SetMaps:LAT:LON];
[Gper release];
```

from this  NSLog(@"setting maps:%@,%@",Lats,lons); I can see the lat and lons values are correct into this method.
However, the map doesnt change to this location.

Whatelse should I do to make it showing new location?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is not related to Xcode by any means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you should learn (Objective-)C memory management and Cocoa conventions better before doing anything further. `+ alloc` returns a new instance of your view controller class, and not the one that is currently displayed.

And begin your class names with a capital letter. And your method names with a lowercase one.

Comment: yes, I am new at OjectiveC. so how to call that function without creating new instance?

Comment: @STANLEY Well... without creating a new instance!

Comment: I change that line to secondViewController *Gper; it gives error on [Gper SetMaps:LAT:LON] when it is running;

Comment: @STANLEY Of course it does, because you're using an uninitialized pointer. Sorry but I'm not here to teach you C and Objective-C in one answer, you have to do some research first. It'll be a long time you'll be able to write an application like this, I'm afraid. For the time being, I suggest you grab K&R C and read it carefully.